# Not able to load JSON data into DropDownList in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, dropdown, angularjs-ng-options

I'm getting blank data while loading JSON data into Dropdown using Angular ng-options.

My JSON Values

```
"tagFormat": {
        "displayText": "Tag Format",
        "options": [{
            "value": "js",
            "name": "JS"
        }, {
            "value": "vast",
            "name": "VAST"
        }]
    },
```

HTML View

```
<div class="select_padding">
    <select class="form-control" ng-options="otf.value as otf.name for otf in details.tagFormat.options">
         <option>Select Tag Format</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

here details is my scope variable.

how to get these data and also next time I need to use selected value. so Do I need to bind with ng-model ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working code:

```
    <select class="form-control" ng-options="item as item.name for item in details.tagFormat.options track by item.value" ng-model="selected">
         <option value="">Select Tag Format</option>
    </select>
```

In `$scope.selected` you read the selected item.

Check this example on Codepen: http://codepen.io/beaver71/pen/Vexwmr